# How to enroll fingerprint using digital persona javascript driver v3.0.0

Tags: javascript, java, fingerprint, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

The Javascript API of digital persona v3.0.0 only provides the image of thumbprint, it has not capability to generate the enrollment fmd as available in the C# and Java drivers. is there a way to solve this problem ?